# Confused about Two Contradictory Facts

Tags: forces

When an object hangs from the ceiling, through a rope, the tension force acts upwards, against the force of gravity. However, when a boy pulls a wagon, the tension force acts in the direction he is pulling; why is this? Wouldn't the string want to stay on the wagon, thus making the tension force act against the boy's force on the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer...

Consider a rope under tension, now pick any point along the rope. At that point, there isn't one tension force, but tension forces that radiate away from the point and along the rope. In other words there are two forces pointing in opposite directions from the point. This is true for any point along the rope.

This means that the rope in your question acts both upwards and downwards at all points. The same for the rope pulling the wagon - the tension points towards and away from the wagon.

When applying Newton's 2nd law you much first isolate, that is define, the system under consideration. This will fix the direction of the tension force (which will always point away from the system).

In case you are wondering: Are the forces on the object/ceiling/wagon/boy in the question just like this?
No, the tension "force vector" is actually something else called a 2nd rank tensor. It doesn't seem like at this point you need to know the details of this, but I mention it as a compliment to your intuition in recognizing something unusual here and to inform you of some interesting physics ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the tension on the rope acts in both directions. It makes a tension T on the both and it makes a tension T on the train (and by Newton's third law the boy and the wagon also make a reaction force T on the rope). Same with the example of the ceiling. The difference in the two examples was just what end of the rope you are paying attention, but the tension acts  at both ends.

Comment: If the force of tension acts both ways, how does the wagon move?

Comment: the force is acting on different bodies. When you analize motion you always watch at the forces that act upon a specific body, not the ones it does onto others. In teh case of the train, it receives a fore T that moves it. The fact that he also makes a force T do not influence its movement. Actually, remember  Newton's second law.